# SQL Scalar UDF returns expected results and then returns a consistent weird value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im using a SQL Scalar UDF to calculate the Weighted Moving Average for a particular stock. 
I created the following UDF [dbo].[fn_WeightedMovingAverageClosePriceCalculate].  (See below )

However, I get mixed results when calling the function. This is while executing both queries at the same time, but I'm getting different results.  I took the code out of the function in a query, plugged in my test values and it works perfectly (WMA13  = 1540.8346).  Would love to hear why I'm getting the value of 15.7313 as WMA13 in the second resultset, when both the queries are exactly the same.

[image]

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_WeightedMovingAverageClosePriceCalculate]
(
@SecCode varchar(100),
@StartDateId int,
@MovingAverageCount int 
)
RETURNS decimal(18,4)
AS
BEGIN

--Generate the Weighting Factor
Declare @WeightingFactor as decimal(18,8)
Set @WeightingFactor  = (@MovingAverageCount*(@MovingAverageCount+1))/2  -- using the formula n(n+1)/2


-- Declare the return variable here
Declare @MovingAverage as decimal (18,4) 
Set @MovingAverage = 0
if @MovingAverageCount <> 0 
begin 
Select @MovingAverage  = SUM(ClosePrice*RowNum/@WeightingFactor)from 
(   
    Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by BusinessDateId asc) AS RowNum , ClosePrice, BusinessDateId
    from 
    (

        Select TOP (@MovingAverageCount) ClosePrice, BusinessDateId 
                from dbo.BhavCopy
                where BusinessDateId <=@StartDateId
                and SecCode = @SecCode
                and Exchange  = 'NSE'
        order by BusinessDateId desc
    )d

)a
end 

Set @WeightingFactor = 0
Set @MovingAverageCount = 0


-- Return the result of the function
Return @MovingAverage
```

See Data that i'm working with : 
[image: Data That Im working with]

So there were 2 different execution plans, which surprised me as well.
Right one  - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vPHbAS3X8Jmua8E5ReUgumsiUuovtL4p/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Wrong one - https://drive.google.com/file/d/180-Z3bMtzvV31En6z-zA-sVM_yPNyaQv/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: Use a date/time datatype for dates, not `integer`.

Comment: How would using date/time data types help?

Comment: Using the right data types prevents all sorts of problems.

Comment: thanks for the help, but all my other functions work well with the dateId. this is defintiely not the cause of the issue.

Comment: Can you provide the XML for the actual execution plans for both results?

Comment: And I agree the stuff about date is irrelevant here as you aren't doing any datetime manipulation of the value or using any properties of it other than ordering and `<` so the fact that it happens to represent a key to a date dimension or similar is not at all important. It doesn't explain different results

Comment: I think you are complicating the moving average calculation. Refer to the post: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4206/sql-server-tsql-code-to-calculate-a-moving-average/

Comment: @VenkataramanR - Thanks for the reply, however, Im calculating weighted moving averages, which is weighted towards the latest price.
Please see this link which explains the difference. -  https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/071414/whats-difference-between-moving-average-and-weighted-moving-average.asp

Comment: @MartinSmith - I should have thought to add the execution plan.  So I've gotten 2 different execution plans.  I've added my drive links so you can read the files.  I'm not overly experienced reading these XML's but I'm giving it a go

Comment: I haven't the time to have a proper look at it now but in the "wrong results" one the UDF is inlined and in the one with correct results it is not inlined. Could be a bug with scalar UDF inlining, you can disable it for that function. Also try installing the latest CU as there have been quite a few fixed bugs in this area and you are still on RTM (`15.0.2000.5`)

Comment: Any idea why it is toggling between being inlined and not being inlined? Are you doing anything different or is it just random?

Comment: @MartinSmith - Thanks for the help. I updated with the CU, but no effect. My guess is that I am using ROWCOUNT () in the UDF. I'll try to stop this function executing inline.

Comment: Just add `with inline = off` to the definition

Comment: @ MartinSimth  -  Done Thanks for guiding me throught this headache !!
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/scalar-udf-inlining?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: How do I mark this as a answer to you  ?

Comment: @stickybit - demo of the issue added with no datetime columns in sight...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug with scalar UDF inlining and how it treats scalar aggregates in some cases ([report](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/40660090-inlined-scalar-udf-returns-incorrect-result-for-sc)).

The issue is that when inlined the execution plan contains a stream aggregate with

```
ANY(SUM(ClosePrice*CONVERT_IMPLICIT(decimal(19,0),[Expr1007],0)/[Expr1002]))
```

The nesting of `SUM` in `ANY` here is incorrect.

`ANY` is an internal aggregate that returns the first `NOT NULL` value that it finds (or `NULL` if none were found.

So in your case the stream aggregate receives its first row (very likely to be the one with the lowest `BusinessDateId` out of the 13 eligible) - calculates the `SUM(ClosePrice*RowNum/@WeightingFactor)` for that row, passes the partial aggregate result to `ANY` - which considers its work done and uses that as the final result. Any contribution to the `SUM` from the remaining 12 rows is lost.

You can add `with inline = off` to the function definition to disable it until the issue is fixed.

A simpler demo is below (tested on SQL Server 2019 RTM and RTM-CU2)

### Setup

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Numbers

GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Numbers(Number INT UNIQUE CLUSTERED);

INSERT INTO dbo.Numbers VALUES (NULL), (23), (27), (50);
```

### Demo 1

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnDemo1]()
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Result as int, @Zero as int = 0
SELECT @Result = SUM(Number + @Zero) from dbo.Numbers 
RETURN @Result
END

GO

DECLARE @Zero INT = 0
SELECT SUM(Number + @Zero) AS SanityCheck, 
         dbo.fnDemo1() AS FunctionResult
FROM dbo.Numbers 
OPTION (RECOMPILE) --I found the inlining happened more reliably with this
```

Demo 1 Results

```
+-------------+----------------+
| SanityCheck | FunctionResult |
+-------------+----------------+
|         100 |             23 |
+-------------+----------------+
```

[image]

All 4 rows were read from the clustered index in key order. After the first one was read the `SUM` was `NULL`. After the second one was read the `SUM` was `23`. `ANY` can then stop and considers its work done. The remaining two rows were still read but don't contribute to the returned `ANY(SUM())`.

### Demo 2

Without the intermediate `@Result` variable a spurious error is thrown

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnDemo2]()
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Zero as int = 0;
RETURN (SELECT SUM(Number + @Zero) from dbo.Numbers);
END

GO

Select dbo.fnDemo2()
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

[image]

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line xx
>
> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery > > follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Only one row actually comes out of the stream aggregate but the stream aggregate also calculates a `COUNT(*)` along with the `ANY(SUM())`. This is not wrapped in `ANY` so totals `4` in this case. It is used in the assert operator to give the bogus error that too many rows will be returned.

### Demo 3

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnDemo3]()
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Zero as int = 0;
RETURN (SELECT SUM(Number + @Zero) from dbo.Numbers GROUP BY ());
END

GO

Select dbo.fnDemo3()
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

This generates a stack dump and a different error

> Msg 8624, Level 16, State 17, Line xx
>
> Internal Query Processor Error: The query processor could not produce a query plan. For more information, contact Customer Support Services.